# Adjusting transparency of layer in certain areas of map using QGIS

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity

In the following map, I'd like to adjust the transparency of the Delaware River so that it is more opaque in the area directly adjacent to Philadelphia county, and more transparent in the areas outside of Phila Co., i.e. in the areas highlighted in yellow.

[image]

I've done this in ArcGIS using the Effects toolbar and am wondering if there is a QGIS equivalent.

Comment: Is Philadelphia boundary placed in a separate layer from the adjacent country layer, or are they located in one (same) layer?

Comment: @ahmadhanb The Philadelphia boundary is in a layer separate from the adjacent county layers.

Comment: Then you can use case 1 in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

If the philadelphia is located in a separate layer from the adjacent boundary layer, then you need to use Inverted Polygon Style as follows:

1. Right-click Philadelphia layer and select create `Duplicate layer`
2. Move the duplicate layer above the river layer
3. Right click the `duplicate layer -> Symbology -> Inverted Polygons`.
4. Select the filled color that you want to be either gray or white as you like.
5. Adjust the transparency of the duplicate layer to the desired range. It is located under `Symbology -> Layer Rendering -> Opacity`, and there is a slider for opacity.

**Case 2**

If all the county boundaries including Philadelphia are located in one single layer.It is easier, use Steps 1, 2, and 5 only.

Answer (score 2):

You could clip the river layer by the Philadelphia boundary, creating new layer that is just that part of the river in Philly county. To perform the clip, use Vector->GeoProcessing Tools->Clip. If Philly county if part of a layer with the other counties, select Philly, then in the clip dialog click on Selected Features only. Add this layer to the map, and use the slider in the Layer Rendering part of the Symbology dialog to make the original river layer as transparent as you like.